# Set and Pass (method="POST") a id or variable from a drop down to another page , I tried a lot but

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a id for each drop down content .

just like i want to send  id=1101 for Cse-1101

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn",style="center">Level-1 Term -1 </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="downloads.php">CSE-1101</a>
  <a href="cEEE-1163.php">EEE-1163</a>
  <a href="cMe-1181.php">ME-1181</a>
  <a href="cMATH-1141.php">MATH-1141</a>
  <a href="cPHY-1103.php">PHY-1103</a>
  <a href="cHUM-1101.php">HUM-1101</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not make POST requests using normal links, you’d need to use a form for that to begin with.

Comment: it is not possible sir ?

Comment: Is _what_ not possible? Your question is rather unclear at the moment.

Comment: You should probably just use GET instead, and append the value as a parameter in the query string.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than having a separate PHP script for each course, I recommend you have one script that handles all of them.

Also, only passing the numeric portion will not be useful because even in this sample data set, you'd have a problem. `CSE-1101` and `HUM-1101` have the same number but are different courses.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="center">Level-1 Term -1</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="course-details.php?course-id=CSE-1101">CSE-1101</a>
        <a href="course-details.php?course-id=EEE-1163">EEE-1163</a>
        <a href="course-details.php?course-id=ME-1181">ME-1181</a>
        <a href="course-details.php?course-id=MATH-1141">MATH-1141</a>
        <a href="course-details.php?course-id=PHY-1103">PHY-1103</a>
        <a href="course-details.php?course-id=HUM-1101">HUM-1101</a>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Then in **course-details.php** get the Id.

```php
$id = $_GET['course-id'];
```

and do whatever you need.